# How to make strings from Resources.resw show up in the designer?

Tags: c#, xaml, translation, windows-8.1, win-universal-app

In the `Shared` project of my universal app I have two folders inside of the `Strings` folder, `en-US` and `sv-SE`. Inside of both folders I have `Resources.resw` files. These contain the strings for my app.

When I run the app I'm able to see the strings, mapped using `x:Uid`, but I'm not able to see the string when using the designer designer.

Moving the English `Resources.resw` file to the root of `Strings` generates an error, telling me there is no Resources.resw file for the default language (en-US). Also, it does not make the strings appear in the editor.

Is it possible to make the resources from a *.resw appear in the designer?

Comment: This situation is really a shame. Has anyone seen if vs14 improves on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd be surprised if your other project actually works as you think.  Strings in *.resw files are not automatically understood for the designer.  Given this:

```
<TextBlock x:Uid="MyWelcomeMessage" />
```

In the designer would show an empty `TextBlock` because the designer doesn't get the localized resource at design-time.  The recommendation is to use some placeholder values for those items you are localizing with resources.

Comment: Hm, checking that old project again I can't get it to work. Probably it never did either and I just have a very bad memory. But, will x:Uid always override the hardcoded value?